# $scope.$broadcast and $rootScope.$broadcast not fired the event on IE9

Tags: angularjs

I have a web application on AngularJS. I am facing the problem in broadcasting and receiving events in IE9 browser. In other browsers it is working fine. My problem scenario is, I have 2 controllers. One is parent controller and other is child controller. I am broadcasting the event from parent controller like this

```
$scope.$broadcast('MyBroadcastEvent');
```

On child controller, I am handling the event like this

```
$scope.$on('MyBroadcastEvent', function(event, args) {
    console.log("Event Handled");
});
```

But child controller not receive the event in IE9. I have tried using $timeout with passing the timeout period and without passing the timeout period like below but still the child controller not receive the event.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('MyBroadcastEvent');
});
```

and

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('MyBroadcastEvent');
}, 1100);
```

I found the following alternate ways to send and receive events but not sure if they will work on IE9.

http://jonathancreamer.com/an-angular-event-bus-with-postal-js/ 
https://github.com/jseppi/angular-queue

Please suggest any workaround to solve this issue in IE9 or suggest any alternate way to receive event on child controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397217/angularjs-event-not-firing-from-rootscope

Comment: Actually broadcasting should work in IE9  as described in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie). You could use $watch.